# NodeJS - Assertion in callback function not failing Mocha unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js

I am trying to run Mocha unit tests on a NodeJS application, but am having a problem in dealing with assertions inside a callback function.

For example, I have the following unit test:

```
describe('PDF manipulation', () => {
    it('Manipulated test file should not be null', async () => {
        fs.readFile('test.pdf', async function (err, data){
            if (err) throw err;
            let manipulatedPdf = await manipulate_file(data);
            expect(manipulatedPdf).to.be.not.null;
        });
    });
});
```

When the unit test runs, I intentionally make `manipuldatedPdf` null to verify that the assertion is working.

The assertion comparison completes successfully, but the unit test shows as a passing test and prints out a warning related to unhandled promise rejections:

```
(node:13492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: expected null not to be null
    at ...
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:13492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

From trying to resolve the issue, it looks like I need to be able to `.catch()` any exceptions being thrown inside `readFile`'s callback function, but adding something like the following results in `TypeError: (intermediate value).catch is not a function`:

```
describe('PDF manipulation', () => {
    it('Manipulated test file should not be null', async () => {
        fs.readFile('test.pdf', (async function (err, data){
            if (err) throw err;
            let manipulatedPdf = await manipulate_file(data);
            expect(manipulatedPdf).to.be.not.null;
        }).catch(error => console.log(error)));
    });
});
```

Is there a way to handle these assertion failures to make the unit test fail?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Answer (score 4):

You should use mocha's [done](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) callback when making assertions in a callback.
`Done` callback takes an error as a first argument so it makes sense to wrap the assertion in the try/catch block in order to get a meaningful error when the assertion fails:

```
describe('PDF manipulation', () => {
  it('Manipulated test file should not be null', (done) => {
    fs.readFile('test.pdf', async function (err, data){
      if (err) throw err;
      let manipulatedPdf = await manipulate_file(data);
      try {
        expect(manipulatedPdf).to.be.not.null;
        done()
      } catch (err) {
        done(err)
      }
    });
  });
});
```